# Как объединить функции подсчёта в одну?

Tags: python, tkinter

Делал калькулятор с помощью tkinter, но не понимаю как мне объединить почти полностью совпадающие функции `plus`, `minus`, `um`, `dell` в одну. Сама программа рабочая.

```
from tkinter import *
def is_digit(string):
    if string.isdigit():
       return True
    else:
        try:
            float(string)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
def plus(key):
    n1 = ent1.get().split()
    n2 = ent2.get().split()
    if not(is_digit(n1[0])==True and is_digit(n2[0])==True):
        lbl["text"] = "Вводите только числа!!"
    elif len(n1)>1 or len(n2)>1:
        lbl["text"] = "Вводите только одно число в строке!"
    elif key == "+": 
        s = float(n1[0]) + float(n2[0])
        lbl["text"] = s


def minus():
    n1 = ent1.get().split()
    n2 = ent2.get().split()
    if not(is_digit(n1[0])==True and is_digit(n2[0])==True):
        lbl["text"] = "Вводите только числа!!"
    elif len(n1)>1 or len(n2)>1:
        lbl["text"] = "Вводите только одно число в строке!"
    else: 
        s = float(n1[0]) - float(n2[0])
        lbl["text"] = s

def um():
    n1 = ent1.get().split()
    n2 = ent2.get().split()
    if not(is_digit(n1[0])==True and is_digit(n2[0])==True):
        lbl["text"] = "Вводите только числа!!"
    elif len(n1)>1 or len(n2)>1:
        lbl["text"] = "Вводите только одно число в строке!"
    else: 
        s = float(n1[0]) * float(n2[0])
        lbl["text"] = s

def dell():
    n1 = ent1.get().split()
    n2 = ent2.get().split()
    if not(is_digit(n1[0])==True and is_digit(n2[0])==True):
        lbl["text"] = "Вводите только числа!!"
    elif len(n1)>1 or len(n2)>1:
        lbl["text"] = "Вводите только одно число в строке!"
    else: 
        if float(n2[0])==0:
            lbl["text"] = "На ноль делить нельзя"
        else:
            s = float(n1[0])/float(n2[0])
            lbl["text"] = s

root = Tk()

ent1 = Entry(root, width = 30)
ent2 = Entry(root, width = 30)
btnp = Button(root, text = "+", command = plus, width = 20)
btnm = Button(root, text = "-", command = minus, width = 20)
btnu = Button(root, text = "*", command = um, width = 20)
btnd = Button(root, text = "/", command = dell, width = 20)
lbl = Label(root, width = 30)

ent1.pack()
ent2.pack()
lbl.pack()
btnp.pack()
btnm.pack()
btnu.pack()
btnd.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv

def is_digit(string):
    if string.isdigit():
       return True
    else:
        try:
            float(string)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

def operation(op):
    def inner():
        n1 = ent1.get().split()
        n2 = ent2.get().split()
        if not (is_digit(n1[0]) == True and is_digit(n2[0]) == True):
            lbl["text"] = "Вводите только числа!!"
            return
        if len(n1) > 1 or len(n2) > 1:
            lbl["text"] = "Вводите только одно число в строке!"
            return
        if op == truediv and float(n2[0]) == 0:
            lbl["text"] = "На ноль делить нельзя"
            return

        s = op(float(n1[0]), float(n2[0]))
        lbl["text"] = s

    return inner


root = Tk()

ent1 = Entry(root, width = 30)
ent2 = Entry(root, width = 30)
btnp = Button(root, text = "+", command = operation(add), width = 20)
btnm = Button(root, text = "-", command = operation(sub), width = 20)
btnu = Button(root, text = "*", command = operation(mul), width = 20)
btnd = Button(root, text = "/", command = operation(truediv), width = 20)
lbl = Label(root, width = 30)

ent1.pack()
ent2.pack()
lbl.pack()
btnp.pack()
btnm.pack()
btnu.pack()
btnd.pack()

root.mainloop()
```